# What will happen to our mansion when the time comes to go to the New Jerusalem?

Tags: heaven

Christ said that there are mansions in Heaven for us. (John 14:2-3).
I am wondering that if the time comes for the event of entering into the New Jerusalem then what will be the case for our mansions?
Will it be left or what ?

Comment: This is not an answer, but note: “Mansion” is usually considered a mistranslation. It may be largely metaphorical Im not sure, but regardless a good English for the greek word is “apartment”, even more so than “room”. That said, many (Id say incl myself) see the work of the Holy Spirit in presenting the English speaking world with the King James Bible as authoritative scripture. One could even make the case that “mansion” is better for English world because in the ancient world having your own apartment for one person would be a wonderful state of affairs, akin to having a mansion now.

Comment: @AlBrown "mansion" has an obsolete meaning of an apartment/habitation within a building, typically used in the plural. Incidentally, this verse is cited as one of the most likely usages of that definition

Comment: This *gotquestions.org* article [Do we receive mansions in heaven?](https://www.gotquestions.org/mansions-heaven.html) pretty much answers your question.

Comment: @eques I see. So “mistranslation” is not an entirely accurate characterization of the situation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Before we get too carried away with visions of living in glorious heavenly mansions, or dwelling places, and trying to imagine what the New Jerusalem will be like, bear this in mind:

> Eye hath not seen, nor ear heard, neither have entered into the heart of man, the things which God hath prepared for them that love him (1 Corinthians 2:9 which quotes from Isaiah 65:4).

***In the New Testament symbolic language is used to depict the glory of heaven.***  In Revelation 22:1-11 the analogy of a glorious heavenly city is used, New Jerusalem, coming down from heaven adorned as a bride.  Just as the glory of a man is the woman he’s married to (on earth), so the glory of Christ in heaven is in his bride, whom he symbolically marries.  She is depicted both as a pure woman, and as a glorious city.  This is a picture of future, spiritual events.

When the apostle Paul was “caught up to paradise” (the third heaven), he “heard inexpressible things, things that man is not permitted to tell”.  Paul did not describe what he saw or heard, even if the constraints of human language could have done justice to what he experienced.  Similarly, the apostle John (Revelation 10:3-4) and the prophet Daniel (Daniel 8:26; 9:24; 12:4) were instructed to conceal aspects of the visions they received.

***Some heavenly things must remain mysteries until we get there.***  Let us pay heed to this advice:

> So we fix our eyes not on what is seen, but on what is unseen. For what is seen is temporary, but what is unseen is eternal (2 Corinthians 4:17-18).

Realise that heaven’s value system is far different from earth’s value system.  Material things (such as grand houses) pale into insignificance compared to the spiritual reality that is heaven.  The best thing about heaven is the presence of our Lord and Saviour (1 John 3:2).  We will be face to face with the Lamb of God who loved us and sacrificed Himself so that we can enjoy His presence in heaven for eternity.  https://www.gotquestions.org/heaven-like.html

Rather than speculating on how grand things will be in heaven, we do better to concentrate on being led by the Holy Spirit to have “the mind of Christ” now, while we are still alive.  We should desire to cultivate Jesus’ perspective of humility and obedience (Philippians 2:5-8), compassion (Matthew 9:36), and prayerful dependence on God (Luke 5:16).

Focus on the spiritual and serving God now, and allow God to take care of the heavenly details.

For the avoidance of doubt, here is the answer to this question:

***In the New Testament symbolic language is used to depict the glory of heaven.***

***Some heavenly things must remain mysteries until we get there.***